# Not able to upgrade app with In-App Guidance (Prompts)

Tags: managed-package

We recently introduced Prompts in one of the managed package but after that we were not able to upgrade subscriber org. Is anyone else running into this issues?

**Error**: We couldn't install the package because the prompts are created for an app not available in your org.

[image]

Comment: I suggest raising a case on that . It looks the org does not have the app that has prompt version associated! Do you have the app in the org where this is getting installed ?